# Change Page Title using Angular 2 Router Service

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router

I'm trying to change the page title by using router service. However, the variable always failed to get the value from router service. Can anyone help? Thanks!

vtc.route.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '', component: VtcComponent, children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: "step1", pathMatch: "full" },
        { path: 'step1', component: Step1Component, data:{pageHeader: 'Step1'} },
        { path: 'step2', component: Step2Component, data:{pageHeader: 'Step2'}  },
......
    ]
}
```

];

vtc.component.ts

```
export class VtcComponent implements OnInit {
private subscription: Subscription;
private subscription1: Subscription;
webLinkParameter: string;
brokerInformation: IBroker;
authInfo: IAuth;
pageHeader: string;
constructor(private dataService: VtcDataService, private brokerService: BrokerService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private authService: AuthService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(
        (param: any) => {
            this.webLinkParameter = param['brokerid'];
        });

    //This is the part that the variable trying to get value from router service
    this.subscription1 = this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(res => {this.pageHeader = res['pageHeader']});

    console.log("pageHeader: " + this.pageHeader);
....
}
```

The variable pageHeader always shows "undefined" in the console output, which means it didn't get any value from router service at all. Did I miss anything here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The data lives on the component attached to the route. So the parent route which loads VtcComponent does not have access to the data passed into the child route unless you use the [firstChild property](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html), which accesses the first child on the route tree. Such as by:

```
    this.subscription1 = this.activatedRoute.firstChild.data.subscribe(d => this.pageHeader = d['pageHeader'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! We decided to use PageService to solve our problem and it works now.